# generate random id number within angular template just once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to know the way for generating random id in angular template once the page loads. The problem I am facing is that every second I get different ID in the two spans. I want it to be the same on both places and dont want it to change its value every second. Here is my simple template:

```
<main class="has-header has-padding">
<div id = "command">-ID:<span>{{vm.getRandomId()}}</span> -connect  -run</div>
    <hr>
<div id = "command">-ID:{{vm.getRandomId()}}</div>
```

my controller:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myController.ctrl', myController);

    myController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function screenSharingCtrl($scope) {
        angular.extend(this, {
            getRandomId:getRandomId
        });

        function getRandomId() {
            return Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
        }
    }
})();
```

Sorry if it is a duplicate question.
Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just change the binding to

```
{{ vm.id }}
```

and your viewmodel to

```
function screenSharingCtrl($scope) {

        function getRandomId() {
            return Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
        }

        this.id = (typeof this.id === 'undefined') ? getRandomId() : this.id; 
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand the second snippet:
this.id = (typeof this.id === 'undefined') ? getRandomId() : this.id; 
where to put it?

Comment: perfect! Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: Is there an easy way to make angular start it from 1 and auto increment the id on opening the page.
For example I open it for first time id = 1. Then I close the browser and then open for second time from another client. The id would be 2?

Comment: `localstorage` would be an option [quick intro](http://lukepeters.me/blog/an-introduction-to-html5-localstorage). Make sure you convert the string to a number though.

Comment: wait, "from another client"? you need to store it on the server somehow

Comment: I dont think the local storage should work in this case because if I open the page from another client/workstation the id will not be incremented

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87394/discussion-between-stefan-baiu-and-nevyanovl).